# Save the output of command prompt to text file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to save the user name and full name to a text file.
When I do that, only the user name is displayed in the text file.

I need both **User name** and **Full Name** in this form:

---

User name: XXXXXXX

Full Name: XXXXXXX

---

I would also like the file to be named with Full Name instead of the User name.

```
 net user "%USERNAME%" /domain |FIND /I "Full Name" & echo User Name: %username% >%username%.txt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is only applying to the last command (echo).  Use paretheses to apply it to the whole command pipeline.

```
(net user "%USERNAME%" /domain |FIND /I "Full Name" & echo User Name: %username%) >%username%.txt
```

To use the full name as the filename, you could use `FOR /F` to parse the output and store the name into the variable.

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('net user %username% /domain ^| find "Full Name"') do set FileName="%%b.txt"
```

Run this command in your script first, and then change the output file to `>%FileName%.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ryan. How do I get the Full Name to be the file name?

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining your answer! :)